# MonoGame on Surface Pro

Tags: c#, windows-8, tablet, monogame

I have a MonoGame Visual Studio 2012 project that runs perfectly on my PC. Unfortunately it does not run on my new Surface Pro, crashing with exception:

> The type initializer for 'OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode' threw an exception.

I tried MonoGame under Xamarin with the very same results on this machine. I upgraded the Intel graphics drivers but the error remains.

The issue also presents on the project templates that MonoGame creates, so it is not even an issue with my code.

How do I make MonoGame work on a Surface Pro then?

Comment: See: [MonoGame Windows Project on surface pro](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/445382). It is a driver issue.

Comment: I would accept that as an answer then!

The problem is that I tried upgrading the graphics drivers, but it does not seem to produce any results.

Comment: It said to look at the [manufacturers driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=22842).

Comment: If you please put that as an answer then I will accept it!

Answer (score 2):

See: [MonoGame Windows Project on surface pro](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/445382).

Downloading the latest [manufacturers driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=22842) for the 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with: Intel® HD Graphics 4000/2500 should fix the issue.